# C# LINQ - reading an XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i need to store all the informationen from the xml in an array. My code doesn't work, because I always get just the first item from the xml.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://www.thefaxx.de/xml/nano.xml");
        var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("items")
                    select new
                    {
                        Title = item.Element("item").Element("title").Value,
                        Description = item.Element("item").Element("description").Value
                    };

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(item.Title);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
    var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                select new
                {
                    Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                    // *** NOTE: xml has "desc", not "description"
                    Description = item.Element("desc").Value
                };
```

It is a *little* hard to be sure without sample xml - but it looks like you intend to loop over all the `<item>...</item>` elements - which is what the above does. Your original code loops over the (single?) `<items>...</items>` element(s), then fetches the first `<item>...</item>` from within it.

---

edit after looking at the xml; this would be more efficient:

```
    var items = from item in xdoc.Root.Elements("item")
                select new {
                    Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                    Description = item.Element("desc").Value
                };
```